# Can I use Blockfrost to call custom endpoints of my Plutus offchain contract?

Tags: plutus, blockfrost

Blockcfrost-related question. Can we expose our own custom endpoints in our off-chain Plutus contract, and use your API to send requests from our own frontend client? For example, if I expose an endpoint named "collect-funds" in my Plutus off-chain contract, can I call that endpoint from my react app via your API to execute my Plutus contract functionality which is related to that endpoint? Super thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can [blockfrost-haskell](https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-haskell) from you off-chain code to call the Blockfrost API.

Or you can use [Blockfrost endpoint integration for the PAB](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/pab-blockfrost) available in PAB directly.